# Different JS Namespace declarations

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, javascript-namespaces

I wonder, are the following code example the same?

Version 1:

```
var myNamespace = {};
myNamespace.say = function() {...}
```

Version 2 (JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/542wbkat/) :

```
var myNamespace = new function() {
    this.say = function() {...};
}
```

Version 3:

```
var myNamespace = {
    "say": function() {...}
}
```

I come from a pure Java background and this is kinda confusing to me. I tested code an it all works fine, but I wonder if JS internally handles the versions differently. Before writing this post I read a doc on the Mozilla Dev Network https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects but I still can't wrap my head arround.

Additional question:
Can the functions I created in the 'myNamespace' namespace be instantiated (as instances of a class)? Or am I getting this

Cheers!

Comment: Well I am right now cleaning up old code and I found 3 different files where Version 2 was used and the program I am cleaning up was running successfully quiet a while. I even tested the scripts myself.

Comment: I created a fiddle for version 2 which works:
https://jsfiddle.net/542wbkat/

Comment: Don't use `new` with functions....

Comment: This is too broad. You actually have 3+ different questions here, all of which are dupes of existing questions. Google "what does 'new' do in javascript" for (several) good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

all way is a object

there is no difference

```
console.log(typeof myNamespace);    
// object
```

Comment: And there isn't any java-equivalent difference like one declaration making the functions static or instantiatable?